# Jest failing async test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am getting the current error

```
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

    at Function.isPendingSpecException
```

I think the issue comes down to this line of code

```js
TokenRepositoryMock.findTokenRecordByToken.mockImplementationOnce(
  async () => null,
)
```

If I change that code to this I no longer get the error.

```js
TokenRepositoryMock.findTokenRecordByToken.mockImplementationOnce(
  async () => ValidToken,
)
```

I need this function to return null so I can test the failing code.
Here is the method I am testing

```js
public static validate(): Middleware {
  return async (ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<void> => {
    const token = ctx.data.get('token')

    const tokenRecord: AccountToken | null = await TokenRepository.findTokenRecordByToken(
      token,
    )

    if (!tokenRecord) {
      ctx.status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
      throw new InvalidTokenError()
    }

    ctx.data.set('token', tokenRecord)

    await next()
  }
}
```

I have seen a few posts online stating that it could be an error with Intellij IDEA (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54425293/9431766) and jest 24.0.0, however, I am running 26.6.3 and also running this both via PhpStorm and command line and still getting the same error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify something `async` functions return Promises. That's all the `async` keyword does: it wraps your "return" data as a promise, so `async () => 4` is _identical_ to `() => Promise(resolve => resolve(4))`, and can be `then`'d because _it is a Promise_: `(async () => 4).then(console.log)` will log "4" because it's just waiting for the promise to resolve. So an `async () => Promise...` makes no sense: now you're returning a promise for a promise. Either use `async () => {}` or `function() { return Promise.resolve(); }` if you need a pre-resolved promise.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ah yes, that was a mistake in my code, I was testing to see if that was actually what was causing the error I was receiving, but it wasn't.  I have figured it out now, randomly, I will update my code here and post what I did to fix it

Comment: Don't: instead, update your post only to show the _actual_ code that you had that was the problem, then post an _answer_ that explains how to fix it (which you will be able to do tomorrow, to prevent spam). Never edit a post to say "I fixed it, here's how".

Comment: Oh no i meant that I was to update the code to remove the promise part, and then post the answer to what I found worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did find something in my code that fixed it.

I am importing `TokenRepository` from an external module that we have.

`import { TokenRepository } from '@company/library'`

And then to mock it I was doing this

```js
jest.mock('@company/library')

const TokenRepositoryMock = mocked(TokenRepository, true)
```

by updating the `jest.mock` path it somehow started to work correctly.

ie.
`jest.mock('@company/library/dist/token/TokenRepository')`

weirdly enough this started to work again